# invalid Xsl format (or) file name

Tags: java, wmic

what i wanted to do is to get all the installed applications in a computer and ihave decided to use the /output command of the command prompt using java. my code was working properly with this line of code in my computer:

```
Process proc = rt.exec("wmic /output:C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\list.csv product get name,version /format:csv ");
```

however, when i try to run the program in another computer, i encounter the "Invalid XSL format or file name" error. I tried reading other problems and i added this line of code before the code above:

```
proc2 = rt.exec("xcopy /y C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\en-US\\*.xsl C:\\Windows\\System32\\");
```

but still nothing happened. the error is still there. anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: What happens when you run the command from the command line? And are there actually files in the `en-US` directory?

Comment: yes there is. it tries to copy the first file, but then it says Access Denied. How can I allow this program to copy?

Comment: If receiving Access Denined, try running java program with admin rights. You may also need to copy XSL files from the 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem\en-US' folder into 'C:\Windows\System32'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/a9beeed3-99f0-4627-ba1e-aa0161fa58c9#be9e599a-5cd8-4238-9918-df650a98c66b) in Windows 7 WMIC. When you use (for example) Dutch regional settings in an English Windows installation, WMIC searches for the xsl files inside `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\nl-NL`, instead of `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\en-US` where they are.

Workarounds:

1. Copy or move the `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\en-US\*.xsl` files up into the `C:\Windows\system32\wbem\` folder.
2. Change your regional settings to match your Windows language version, log out and back in.
3. Specify the full path: `WMIC process get /format:"%WINDIR%\System32\wbem\en-US\csv"`.